# How to edit a systemd timer where persistent=true?

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

This on a Raspberry Pi 4 running Buster.

I have a systemd timer that runs once a day at a particular time. I also have persistent=true. I want to change that time. But, if I edit the file with a new time, save the file and then run **sudo systemctl daemon-reload**, the timer runs immediately.

I understand that this is because persistent=true stores the timer time on disk. I also read (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/systemctl.1.html) that to avoid this I should run: systemctl clean --what=state [timer unit]

But, this doesn't work:

```
pi@raspcondo:~/webcam $ sudo systemctl clean --what=state kamvideo.timer
systemctl: unrecognized option '--what=state'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

[Edit] Another reference: [systemd.timer — Timer unit configuration](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html)

Comment: First, you should check the manpages for the version appropriate to your system: https://manpages.debian.org/buster/systemd/systemctl.1.en.html https://manpages.debian.org/buster/systemd/systemd.timer.5.en.html. Those links are for much newer versions.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that I was referring to obsolete man pages and providing me with links to more current pages. I've read through both and find that the "clean" command no longer exists. However, I'm not smart enough to find an alternative in the reference man pages. So, my original question stands: How to edit a systemd timer where persistent=true?

Comment: It's the other way around - you were looking at manpages for systemd 251 (or thereabouts, man7.org and freedesktop.org typically host the latest docs). The `clean` command is for newer systemd versions. If you can upgrade to [Bullseye](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/systemd/systemctl.1.en.html), you can use `systemctl clean` there.

Comment: See, I told you I wasn't too smart. I'm not about to upgrade to Bullseye yet, so I still need to figure out how to edit these systemd timer files. Perhaps the easiest thing to do is just set persistent to off and proceed.

Comment: Yep, that worked.